# v4 Chart.js positive negative line color

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have an Ajax filter that pulls positive and negative values from posts. These values I am showing using chart.js. All works but i want to make the lines between two points different color.

For example values [1000,-500,1000,-500]
From 1000 to 0 the line color to be blue and from 0 to -500 yellow. Then from -500 to 0 yellow and from 0 to 1000 blue etc.
I tried to experiment with the plugin option but without much of success using the examples here - [Chart JS plugin to change line color depending on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60190586/chart-js-plugin-to-change-line-color-depending-on-value)

Here is my code so far:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        // Variable to store the chart instance
        var myLineChart;
            
        // Variables to store the previous values of dropdowns
        var prevSport = $('#sport').val();
        var prevSportType = $('#sport_type').val();
        
        $('#filter').on('click', function () {
            // Get the current values of dropdowns
            var currentSport = $('#sport').val();
            var currentSportType = $('#sport_type').val();

            if (!currentSport || !currentSportType) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        action: 'filter_posts',
                        sport: currentSport,
                        sport_type: currentSportType,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.error) {
                            $('.notice').html(response.message);
                            return;
                        } else {
                            $('.notice').remove();
                        }
                        // Destroy existing chart if it exists
                        if (myLineChart) {
                            myLineChart.destroy();
                        }

                        // Create a new chart
                        updateChart(response);
                    },
                });
                return;
            }

            // Check if dropdown values have changed
            if (currentSport !== prevSport || currentSportType !== prevSportType) {
                // Update previous dropdown values
                prevSport = currentSport;
                prevSportType = currentSportType;

                // Perform AJAX request only if dropdown values have changed
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        action: 'filter_posts',
                        sport: currentSport,
                        sport_type: currentSportType,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.error) {
                            $('.notice').html(response.message);
                            return;
                        } else {
                            $('.notice').remove();
                        }
                        // Destroy existing chart if it exists
                        if (myLineChart) {
                            myLineChart.destroy();
                        }

                        // Create a new chart
                        updateChart(response);
                    },
                });
            }
        });

        function updateChart(data) {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myLineChart').getContext('2d');
            
            myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: data.labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        data: data.datasets[0].data,
                        borderColor: function(context) {
                            const chart = context.chart;
                            const {ctx, chartArea} = chart;

                            if (!chartArea) {
                                // This case happens on the initial chart load
                                return;
                            }

                            // Create the gradient
                            const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, chartArea.bottom, 0, chartArea.top);
                            gradient.addColorStop(0, 'blue'); // Change this color to your preference
                            gradient.addColorStop(1, 'yellow'); // Change this color to your preference

                            return gradient;
                        },
                    }],
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            min: -3000,
                            max: 3000,
                        },
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false, // Set display property to false to hide the legend
                        },
                    },
                },
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```